# millisecond and SimpleDateFormat and JXDatepicker conflict in java

Tags: java, date

In my current project I am saving date in millisecond like this:

```
  long f = jXDatePicker1.getDateInMillis();
  //Data is saved in database.
```

Next I am writing a query like this:

```
  long firstDate =  jXDatePicker1.getDateInMillis();
  long secondDate =  jXDatePicker2.getDateInMillis();

  Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
  Calendar cal2 = Calendar.getInstance();

DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();
int rows = model.getRowCount();
if (rows>0){
for(int i=0 ; i<rows; i++)
{model.removeRow(0);}}

String query = "SELECT CODE, AD_DATE, EX_DATE, PLAN_NAME, AMOUNT, DISCOUNT, TOTAL"
        + " FROM ADMISSION_MASTER WHERE AD_DATE>="+firstDate+" AND AD_DATE<="+secondDate+" ";

try{
    conn = new data.connection().db();
    stmtt = conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
    rs = stmtt.executeQuery(query);
    while(rs.next()){
        long F = rs.getLong("AD_DATE"); cal.setTimeInMillis(F);
        long T = rs.getLong("EX_DATE"); cal2.setTimeInMillis(T);
        String frm = sdf.format(cal.getTime());
        String too = sdf.format(cal2.getTime());
        model.addRow (new Object[]{rs.getString(1), frm, too, rs.getString(4), rs.getString(5), rs.getString(6), rs.getString(7)});

    }}
 catch(SQLException ex){}
 finally{try{stmtt.close(); rs.close(); conn.close();}
 catch(SQLException ex){}
```

Now I select date in JXDatePicker. First Date = 5 March, 2014 Second Date : 6 March, 2014.

I never get the 6 March in jtable. I've to select 7 March 2014 for the 6 March Display.
 I assume this is happening for timezone. How to resolve this issue? Please help.

Comment: What RDBMS (flavor of SQL)?  What's the type of `AD_DATE`?  Can we get some sample data and expected results?  [You should be using an exclusive upper bound with date/time/timestamp types regardless](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common) - and that applies to all RDBMSs.  You should be executing a prepared statement (your query is currently safe from SQL Injection only due to typing) - it's the principle of the thing.

Comment: 'AD_DATE' is 'BIGINT'. I am using Derby Database.

Comment: You need to give us sample data - it's really hard to tell what's going wrong just from this.  Why aren't you using one of the built-in date/timestamp types?  Globally, a solar day is about ~48 hours long - should you be using `Date` for "calendar day", or `Timestamp` for "specific points in time?  Getting a timestamp in millis should give an absolute value; if you're using one timezone for both source and query it shouldn't matter.  The db should be in UTC if it's used across timezones - you'd need to adjust at that point.